# Changing color of window resize area

Tags: xorg, raspbian, gui, lxde, openbox

When resizing a window, the area between the area of the current window and the area of the resized window is colored gray. I would like to either change its color to black, or to not draw it at all.

A picture more clearly describes this:
[image: Image showing the gray area.]

I'm not sure how to call this gray area, I have tried searching for terms that I deem similar but those searches didn't turn up any results. If you know a better term for this gray area, please edit the question.
I'm running a default install of Raspbian.

**Update**

On the Openbox wiki one can read the following:

> **drawContents** Resize the program inside the window while resizing. When disabled the unused space will be filled with a uniform color during a resize. [[link]](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Configuration#Resize_.28and_move.29)

How does one set this *uniform color of the unused space*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color of the resize area is defined by the value of the `window.active.client.color` variable (and `window.inactive.client.color`) in the Openbox themerc settings file.

In the case of Raspbian, you can find the default settings file used in `~/.themes/PiX/openbox-3/themerc`.
Editing the file to set the aforementioned `window.active.client.color` to take as value `#000000` will set it to black.

Running `openbox --reconfigure` will load the new settings without having to reboot first.